# ContextMenu like in Android

Tags: java, android, menu, contextmenu

In my application I have already a ContextMenu for a View. It provides some options for a image: Download, Share, Delete....

When "Download" is chosen I'd like to show another ContextMenu-like asking for the format ("jpg,png,...") with a style similar to that image. But I really don't know how to open a new dialog with that appearance

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the ["Create Dialogs"-tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList) on the official Docs. They describe how to create an `AlertDialog` with a List, which looks exactly like your screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [android.com](http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_list.png))</sub>